# Bookmark tabs and recover crashed sessions in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session-restore

In Google Chrome:

1. How to bookmark all tabs currently
   open at once, instead of bookmark
   one by one?
2. Is there some function or plug-in similar to the
   session manager of Firefox, which
   can store the addresses to all
   webpages open before the last
   several crashes, instead of just for
   the last single crash?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/244325/how-to-restore-the-window-of-tabs-crashed-1-day-ago-in-google-chrome/253007#253007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to 1: right click on any open tab and select **Bookmark All Tabs (Shift+Ctrl+D)**

Answer to 2: no. so far I did not see something which could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to how to restore the bookmarked webpages?

Comment: @Tim: when you store all bookmark, Chrome is asking you for a folder name where it stores every single bookmark. just right click on the folder and select **Open all bookmarks**