# Keeping my Google Chrome tabs always intact

Tags: mac, google-chrome, tabs, user-experience

Two days ago I quit [my chrome](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Mac). Yesterday I opened it and used it only in Anonymous Mode. Today I opened it again and my [recently closed "21 tabs" are gone](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=280bf8fda8cb4909&hl=en) from the "Recently Closed" history.

**Is there any way to recover them?** I believe this is only the second time I've ever lost them using this amazing feature. While the similar "Restore from crash" never once failed to appear when needed.

Actually, I have no idea why the whole "Recently Closed" history was empty and missing. It was just when I opened a new tab and closed it, just for testing, that it re-appeared, showing only that one test.

So, I'd also appreciate hints (considering all) that on best ways to never lose the tabs. Currently I'm using [Session Budy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) (as per accepted answer, because for now that's good enough), but it doesn't keep **tab history** nor **forms filled**, unlike  chrome's default restorer and it needs to be installed beforehand.

Things I've tried to avoid this kind of problem:

- Using [some](https://superuser.com/questions/244325/how-to-restore-the-window-of-tabs-crashed-1-day-ago-in-google-chrome/253007#253007) extensions out there with this purpose (to save tabs, I've even used good old FEBE back when chrome sucked and I was on firefox) but those were never as reliable as chrome have been with its native feature.
- Bookmark a group of tabs into my already freaking messed bookmarks... They are messed in big part because I already tried doing that too because it requires doing it regularly and manually, which is really bad for actualy being able to recover from a crash we can't foresee.
- Of course, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> won't help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a while I've been using [Session Budy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) and it looks like one of the best extension of the kind I've tried, definitely have a nicer interface than *FEBE* and *Session Manager*. Just remember configuring it to auto save the session for this purpose.

Today (jun 5th 2011) I had the chance to test it after a crash and it worked almost perfectly. The tab history and few forms I was filling up (but thanks to Lazarus I never lost anything) weren't restored. But that's fine because they could be reason for crashing at the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This is perhaps not exactly what you want but you asked for suggestions:

This plugin saves the tabs as a session with a session manager...

> http://techhamlet.com/2010/05/google-chrome-save-sessions/

Comment: I have not mentioned, but I've tried *Session Manager* before and it did no good.